# Is move constructor necessary on (POD) structs?

Tags: c++, constructor, move

In Paragraph 12.8/15 of the C++11 Standard is defined:

> The implicitly-defined copy/move constructor for a non-union class X performs a memberwise copy/move of its bases and members. [...]

Does this mean that:

```
struct st {
  int a;
  int b;
  // ...
};

// ...
void do_smt(st tmp) {
  st lala(std::move(tmp));
  // ...
}

// ...
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  st test(1, 2);
  do_smt(std::move(test));
}
```

would work without the move constructor?

Comment: Umm...doesn't a move constructor explicitly make it *not* a POD struct?  (C++11 9/6, 9/10)

Comment: *Moving* an `int` (or any other primitive type) is the same as copying, so it'll work the same as copying.

Comment: @Praetorian even if i move the whole struct?

Comment: @Praetorian you don't move a pod you just copy it even the whole struct. physically, a POD is on the stack without indirections to data on the heap

Comment: so is the example just copying the struct twice?

Comment: Think about how the structs exist in memory. How can you move them without copying them? Move for things such as vectors only work because you can copy the pointers to the data on the heap, rather than the whole data.

Comment: @NeilKirk ok thx. than i missunderstood the move sematic.

Comment: @a.lasram I'm not sure why you pinged me in your comment, but anyway, moving/copying a POD has nothing to do with the POD being on the stack. The POD may be dynamically allocated, and could even contain pointer data members that could actually be moved, but the implicitly generated move constructor only gives you memberwise copy/move (which results in a copy operation for pointers). And defining a move constructor explicitly makes the object a non-POD.

Comment: @Praetorian I pinged you by mistake and you're right my assumptions were wrong. thanks for pointing this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will work without the need of specifying the move constructor; in your example, it is possible that the compiler optimizes the move operation by initializing lala instead of test; check the assembler output about that.